# Home Loan Affordability Calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please explain what is wrong with my formula, I'm not getting the desired output. I'm supposed to get 1635153.79 as my answer given the parameters below for my test value = maximum_home_loan(15000*12, 0.1045, 35).

Build a function maximum_home_loan_with_age(PMT, i, start_age) that calculates the maximum home loan that your customer can afford

Assume that start_age is an int value, and start_age < 65

'

```
def maximum_home_loan(PMT, i, n):
    n=0
    total_present_value = 0
    while n <66 :
        total_present_value = PMT * ((1+i)**n - 1) / i  /(1+i)**n
        PV = round(total_present_value, 2)
    return PV
```

'

Comment: ...you have an infinite `while` loop. `n` is initialized to `0` and never changed.

Comment: I have added n = n+1, to increment years, but I'm getting 1719512.61 and my answer should be 1635153.79

Comment: You are not saving any value between loops. Also, you are setting `start_age` to zero (n = 0) first line in the function.

Comment: I did what you told me and still no correct output. Something is wrong with my formula I'm not sure what it is. @figbeam

Comment: So, what is the formula?

Comment: total_present_value = PMT * ((1+i)**n - 1) / i  /(1+i)**n this the one I formulated

Answer (score 0):

your n must not start at 0. n  = 65 - start_age

Comment: def maximum_home_loan(PMT, i, n):
    n=65-n
    total_present_value = 0
    while n <66 :
        n=n+1
        total_present_value = PMT * (((1+i)**n - 1) / i  /(1+i)**n)
        PV = round(total_present_value, 2)
    return PV
print(maximum_home_loan(15000*12, 0.1045, 35)), but it's still not giving the correct  output.

Comment: why do you have n=n+1 ?

Comment: To increment number of years

Comment: The want to know how much you will pay if you start the payment at 35 till you're 65, which you have as n=65-n (30 years). You don't need to increment n cause you have the total number of years already